# Convert array of strings to array of integer [Snowflake]

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently stuck with converting an array containing string values to an array of integers on snowflake. I've tried using a couple of functions like the SPLIT() and STRTOK_TO_ARRAY() on my column and casting the result as both a VARIANT and an INTEGER, and it appears I'm not getting anywhere with this.

So here's my table:

| COL1 |
| --- |
| ["1", "2", "3"] |

and here's the result I want:

| COL1 |
| --- |
| [1, 2, 3] |

I've tried the following sql command on snowflake

```
select SPLIT(COL1, ',')::variant::integer;
```

but I doubt this would work because I'm getting this error instead

```
Failed to cast variant value ["1","2","3"] to FIXED
```

I know this looks basic but i've looked into various forums on this, and I can't really find a good approach

Answer (score 0):

For sample input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(col1 VARIANT)
AS
SELECT '["1", "2", "3"]' UNION ALL
SELECT '["9", "7"]';
```

Query using `FLATTEN` and `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
SELECT COL1, ARRAY_AGG(TRY_CAST(f."VALUE"::TEXT AS INT)) AS COL1_Transformed
FROM tab
,TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT=>TAB.COL1)) AS f
GROUP BY COL1, SEQ;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick reply - I appreciate it. Sorry if I may ask, can we extend this to snowpipe.

The reason I ask is because I'll be fetching this array-type of values from a parquet file on s3 and I'll like to know if I could extend this on the go